# why doesn't delegate work for scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates

I am trying to use jquery delegate to bind to scroll events.

html

```
<div id='parent'>
        <div id='child'>Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#parent {
width:200px;
height:200px;
border:2px solid black;
overflow:auto;        
}
#child {
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:red;    
}
```

javascript

```
$('#parent').delegate('#child', 'scroll', function(){
alert(this)
})
```

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/C6DRR/1/

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: i change the css so child overflows and use jquery.scroll and that works, however there is no 'scroll' event like you have for jquery not that i know of anyway, hence the reason why bin, live etc can not be set for scroll

Comment: Yes you can bind to scroll. http://jsfiddle.net/C6DRR/29/

Comment: You are correct tho that delegate doesn't have a scroll method. If you update your answer, I will mark you correct.

Comment: have updated the answer for you tim

Comment: use .on instead of .deligate see this for solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/41958190/2386727

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i think this may bind your scroll

```
$('#child').live('keyup', function() {
var el = $(this);
if (!el.data("has-scroll")) {
    el.data("has-scroll", true);
    el.scroll(function(){
       //doscrollaction(el);
    });
}
doscrollaction(el);
});
```

as requested by op:

i change the css so child overflows and use jquery.scroll and that works, however there is no 'scroll' event like you have for jquery not that i know of anyway, hence the reason why bin, live etc can not be set for scroll and also why your deligate will not work

Comment: Sorry mate, I need to use delegate.

Comment: sorry its not in use its now $(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);     in version 1.7 +

Comment: Actually, delegate hasn't been deprecated in jQuery 1.7, simply superceded.

Answer (score 38):

Because scroll event does not bubble. 
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

Comment: _In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an <img> element) do not bubble_ according to http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 32):

> why doesn't delegate work for scroll?

Because scroll event doesn't bubble through the DOM.

**But**, on modern browsers (IE>8), you can **capture** scroll **event** to e.g document level or any static container for dynamic element. You have to use javascript `addEventListener()` method passing `true` as `useCapture` parameter, jQuery doesn't support capturing phase:

***Note:*** *in your example, `scroll` event happen to `#parent` level, not `#child`*

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'parent') { // or any other filtering condition        
        console.log('scrolling', event.target);
    }
}, true /*Capture event*/);
```

### -DEMO-

For explanation on difference between event capture/propagation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) or [there](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing).

Be aware, a captured event is always fired **before** any other bubbling event of same kind.

Comment: I just tried this (in firefox) and `event.target.id` is null and target is `HTMLDocument` so I can't filter for a given id of an element.... thoughts?

Comment: @SumNeuron You have to use any filtering condition relevant to specific scrolling element you want to target. As you didn't have posted in your comment any more specific info, i can not help you more.

Comment: I think there is a miscommunication. I have a few ids that I wish to filter for (e.g. el1, el2, el3, etc). However the filter you demonstrate above `event.target.id === <id-of-element-I-want>` doesnt work for me as `event.target.id = undefined`.

Comment: @SumNeuron that means the scrolled elemet has no id attribute defined. If it's a parent or a descendant of scrolled element , you have to use any relevant transversal method.