# Backbone scroll event not firing

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

Backbone scroll event will not fire. The click event and jquery attached scroll works. Here's a fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/cX2UV/

js

```
var TView = Backbone.View.extend({        
    events: {
        'scroll .content': 'loadMore',
        'click .code': 'codeClick'
    },

    loadMore: function() {
        this.$el.append('<p>backbone scrolling</p>');
    },

    codeClick: function() {
        this.$el.append('<p>clicking</p>');
    }
});

new TView({ el: '.target' });

$('.content').scroll(function(){ $('.target').append('jq scrolling...'); });
```

html

```
<div class="target">
<div class="content">
    <div>
        <span class="text">text</span>
        <span class="term">termmm</span>
        <span class="codes"><span class="code">12345</span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="text">text</span>
        <span class="term">termmm</span>
        <span class="codes"><span class="code">12345</span></span>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {margin:1em;}
.content {background:#EEE; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;}
.code{color:#00c}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When binding events to a view with a selector Backbone uses jQuery's `delegate`. As noted in [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253904/why-doesnt-delegate-work-for-scroll), the `scroll` event [doesn't bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html) so the handler can't respond to it.