# jQuery scroll event not firing

Tags: jquery, events

Scroll event not firing. Using jQUery 1.11.1 . 
Tried it this way :

```
$(document).on( 'scroll', '#ulId', function(){
    console.log('Event Fired');
});



$(document).on( 'scroll', '#idOfDivThatContainsULandScroll', function(){
    console.log('Event Fired');
});
```

I'm also using CSS . Is there any possibility , CSS is blocking this event to  ?

This fills $pos:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function(e) {
var $pos = $(window).scrollTop()
});
```

Any idea how I can trigger this event?

Comment: The scroll event doesn't bubble, and can't be delegated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253904/why-doesnt-delegate-work-for-scroll

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo:

> The scroll event doesn't bubble, and can't be delegated.

Use like this:

```
$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
    console.log('Event Fired');
});
```