# jQuery .on() hover not working for HTML5 select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to capture the event when the mouse is hovering over the select box, be it collapsed or expanded. I'm using .on() in the following manner,

```
$(document).on('hover', "select#selectBox", function() {
    alert("done");
  });
```

Please note that I'm using this snippet inside DOM document ready too.

I've tried changing the event to click, scroll, mouseover, mouseenter, etc too.
Doesn't seem to work for those too.

Please point out where I'm going wrong.

I've made a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g9vf1mty/2/

**EDIT**: Thanks for the quick response everyone!
I have fixed my mistakes :)

I have tweaked the JSFiddle a little bit. Now, I'm attempting to scroll the select box with a size lesser than the number of options and have changed the 'hover' event to 'scroll' event. It does not seem to work that way.

I'm using **jQuery 2.1.3**.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/g9vf1mty/8/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g9vf1mty/3/

Comment: Use `mouseover`. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g9vf1mty/4/)

Comment: Your fiddle works when you include jQuery...

Comment: It says `$ is not defined`, it simply means that jquery is not loaded correctly, if you include it everything works fine.

Comment: please see the latest fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g9vf1mty/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to wrap event bound to `document` level inside ready pseudo event. And because you want to delegate event, maybe to hanlde dynamic elements, the correct way would be to bind both `mouseenter & mouseleave` events this way:

*eventually filtering by event type inside handler (in/out)*

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', "#selectBox", function(e) {
  alert("done: " + e.type);
});
```

Comment: Scroll event doesnt bubble which is required for delegating it. See workaround http://stackoverflow.com/a/30476388/1414562

Comment: Thanks for the important information that Scroll event doesn't bubble.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("select#selectBox").hover(function() {
 alert("working");
});
```

use hover function, in the above manner. and more importantly, you missed jQuery library too.

As `on("hover")` was **deprecated form jQuery 1.8**, it won't work on Higher versions of jquery.

Comment: It's not 100% correct, as the `hover()` event works in v1.8.3, it was deprecated from v1.9 or higher. You can check it in the official documentation: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Comment: @fbid, read the authentic source here http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes, which says _Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9_, i used the word deprecated.. :)

Comment: But you aren't delegating events here

Comment: yes, it was deprecated from v.1.8 but you wrote that it won't work on higher version than 1.8, that was not 100% correct, anyway it was just to clarify

Comment: yup.. Thanks for the info then. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use mouseenter event

and include jquery in your fiddle :)

Look also at this (SO question)[[Is it possible to use jQuery .on and hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover])